# Should I use static variables inside a function of a DLL?

Tags: c++, dll, static-variables

I have a DLL written in C++ as follows:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int GetConfig(const char* param_name)
{
    MyConfig config;
    config.LoadConfigFromFile("conf.ini");
    return config.get_config(param_name);
}
```

The `GetConfig(const char* )` is invoked very frequently by different processes. The `LoadConfigFromFile( )` is pretty expensive so I would like to make something static, for example:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int GetConfig(const char* param_name)
{
    static MyConfig config;
    if(!config.HasLoaded())
    {
        config.LoadConfigFromFile("conf.ini");
    }
    return config.get_config(param_name);
}
```

My question is that: is my thought feasible? Are there alternative ways to achieve my needs?

Comment: It's not too horrid and optimization. Note that it would change your programs behavior, however. Previously one could edit the ini and have it kick in immediately, but with a static they'll have to restart the program.

Comment: @StoryTeller It does not matter in my case. Then could you please tell me how I can overcome this situation?

Comment: You'd need to use the OS to fetch and cache the time-stamp of the last file modification. It should still be much faster than reading the entire file, so you'll still see a performance boost, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not direct answer to your question but you asked that alternative ways to achieve needs , probably this will helpful.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HANDLE _configfile;
    FILETIME _configFileTimeCreate, _configFileTimeModified;
    SYSTEMTIME _systemUTC;

    time_t start_time = time(NULL);
    for (;;)
    {
        time_t now = time(NULL);
        time_t diff = now - start_time;

        if ((diff % 10) == 0) {

            _configfile = CreateFile(L"config.txt", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ,  NULL,  OPEN_EXISTING,  FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

            if(_configfile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
                printf("Could not open file, error %ul\n", GetLastError());
                return -1;
            }

            if(!GetFileTime(_configfile, &_configFileTimeCreate, NULL, &_configFileTimeModified)) {
                printf("Something wrong!\n");
                return FALSE;
            } 
            else {
                FileTimeToSystemTime(&_configFileTimeModified, &_systemUTC);
                printf("UTC System Time format:\n");
                printf("Modified on: %02d/%02d/%d %02d:%02d\n", _systemUTC.wDay, _systemUTC.wMonth, _systemUTC.wYear,
                                                               _systemUTC.wHour, _systemUTC.wMinute);
            }

            CloseHandle(_configfile);
        }
        Sleep(1000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```